# Is there a way to acces updated state immediately after dispatching async thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

i have an async thunk function  that gets a user from database and sets it to the state, but i want to set the user to local storage after getting it,

```
//SignIn.tsx

const userState = useAppSelector((state) => state.user);


   const handleSignIn = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const user = await dispatch(signIn({ email, password }));
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(userState));
      console.log(userState);
      navigate('/shop');
};
```

```
//userSlice.ts
export const signIn = createAsyncThunk(
   'user/signIn',
   async ({ email, password }: { email: string; password: string }) => {
      const { user }: UserCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
         auth,
         email,
         password
      );
      const data = await getUser(user);
      return { data, user };
   }
);

const userSlice = createSlice({
   name: 'user',
   initialState,
   reducers: {},
   extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder.addCase(signIn.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
         state.email = action.payload.user.email;
         state.token = action.payload.user.refreshToken;
         state.id = action.payload.user.uid;
         state.avatarUrl = action.payload.data.avatarUrl;
         state.lastName = action.payload.data.lastName;
         state.name = action.payload.data.name;
      });
   }
```

im awaiting the dispatch and then trying to set the user to local storage using updated state, idk why the state doesnt update after awaiting the dispatch, instead of updated state im setting the PREVIOUS state to the local storage, please help, im struggling with this for an hours

Comment: Sounds like you want to store the new `user`, not the old `userState`? See also [why the `useState` set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1048572) - same problem, redux doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are storing current state in local storage, you have to store fetched user

```
const { user } = await dispatch(signIn({ email, password }));
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user);
```

Or you can store user directly in createAsync function

You can unwrap and then store

```
const onClick = () => {
  dispatch(fetchUserById(userId))
    .unwrap()
    .then((originalPromiseResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(originalPromiseResult));
    })
    .catch((rejectedValueOrSerializedError) => {
      // handle error here
    })
}
```